# Showing Bitmap Images in WPF via C#

Tags: wpf, icons, bitmapimage

What I am trying to do is so simple but I am having a hard time making it work. I saw some posts along the same lines but I still have questions.

I have a MenuItem object called mnuA. All I want is set the icon property programatically in C#. I have tried the following

a) `mnuA.Icon = new BitmapImage{UriSource = new Uri(@"c:\icons\A.png")};`
Results: Instead of showing the actual icon, I get the class name (`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`)

b) `mnuA.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\icons\A.png"));`
Results: Instead of showing the actual icon, I get the path of the image (`file:///c:/icons/A.png`)

What am I doing wrong? Do I really need a converter class for something simple like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\icons\A.png"));
mnuA.Icon = img;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a long shot, but try something like:

> Uri u = new Uri(...); mnuA.Icon = new
>   BitmapImage(u);

What it seems its happening is that your icon is getting converted to a string.